# Multiplying values in an array using IMUL instruction produces incorrect values

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, assembly, x86

I'm picking up ASM language and trying out the IMUL function on Ubuntu Eclipse C++, but for some reason I just cant seem to get the desired output from my code.

> Required:
>
> Multiply the negative elements of an integer array int_array by a specified integer inum

Here's my code for the above:

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void multiply_function();

// Variables
int iaver, inum;
int int_ar[10] = {1,2,3,4,-9,6,7,8,9,10};

int main()
{
    inum = 2;
    multiply_function();    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%d ",int_ar[i]);
    }
}
```

ASM code:

```
extern int_ar
extern inum
global multiply_function

multiply_function:

    enter 0,0
    mov ecx, 10
    mov eax, inum

multiply_loop:
    cmp [int_ar +ecx*4-4], dword 0 
    jg .ifpositive 
    mov ebx, [int_ar +ecx*4-4]
    imul ebx
    cdq
    mov [int_ar +ecx*4-4], eax
    loop multiply_loop
    leave
    ret

.ifpositive:
    loop multiply_loop
    leave
    ret
```

---

### The Problem

For an array of: `{1,2,3,4,-9,6,7,8,9,10}` and `inum`, I get the output `{1,2,3,4,-1210688460,6,7,8,9,10}` which hints at some sort of overflow occurring.

Is there something I'm missing or understood wrong about how the IMUL function in assembly language for x86 works?

---

### Expected Output

The output I expected is `{1,2,3,4,-18,6,7,8,9,10}`

---

### My Thought Process

My thought process for the above task:

1)  Find which array elements in array are negative, for each positive element found, do nothing and continue loop to next element

```
 cmp [int_ar +ecx*4-4], dword 0 
 jg .ifpositive 

 .ifpositive:
    loop multiply_loop
    leave
    ret
```

2)  Upon finding the negative element, move its value into register EBX which will serve as SRC in the IMUL SRC function. Then extend register EAX to EAX-EDX where the result is stored in:

```
mov ebx, [int_ar +ecx*4-4]
    imul ebx
    cdq
```

3)  Move the result into the negative element of the array by using MOV:

```
mov [int_ar +ecx*4-4], eax
```

4)  Loop through to the next array element and repeat the above 1)-3)

Comment: I suspect that `inum` is not defined as a constant but as a value in memory and you are multiplying by the address of `inum` and not the value at `inum`

Comment: Apologies, i'll add details!

Comment: yup its loop multiply_loop.

Comment: inum was defined as a variable constant whose value is transferred into the EAX register

Comment: Your _C_ code didn't match what was in your assembly, and the the labels for the example needed to be `multiply_loop`. I added extern and global lines to your ASM code to make the example usable. If somehow it isn't your intentions you need to provide us a proper [mcve]. The modifications I have made should still demonstrate the issue for future readers.

Comment: Did you ever fix/resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reason for Incorrect Values

If we look past the inefficiencies and unneeded code and deal with the real issue it comes down to this instruction:

```
mov eax, inum
```

What is `inum`? You created and initialized a global variable in *C* called `inum` with:

```
int iaver, inum;
[snip]
inum = 2;
```

`inum` as a variable is essentially a label to a memory location containing an `int` (32-bit value). In your assembly code you need to treat `inum` as a pointer to a value, not the value itself. In your assembly code you need to change:

```
mov eax, inum
```

to:

```
mov eax, [inum]
```

What your version does is moves the address of `inum` into *EAX*. Your code ended up multiplying the address of the variable by the negative numbers in your array. That cause the erroneous values you see. the square brackets around `inum` tell the assembler you want to treat `inum` as a memory operand, and that you want  to move the 32-bit value at `inum`into *EAX*.

---

### Calling Convention

You appear to be creating a 32-bit program and running it on 32-bit Ubuntu. I can infer the possibility of a 32-bit Linux by the erroneous value of -1210688460 being returned. -1210688460 = 0xB7D65C34 divide by -9 and you get 804A06C. Programs on 32-bit Linux are usually loaded starting at 0x8048000

Whether running on 32-bit Linux or 64-bit Linux, assembly code linked with 32-bit C/C++ programs need to abide by the [*CDECL* calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl):

> cdecl
>
> The cdecl (which stands for C declaration) is a calling convention that originates from the C programming language and is used by many C compilers for the x86 architecture.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) In cdecl, subroutine arguments are passed on the stack. Integer values and memory addresses are returned in the EAX register, floating point values in the ST0 x87 register. **Registers EAX, ECX, and EDX are caller-saved, and the rest are callee-saved**. The x87 floating point registers ST0 to ST7 must be empty (popped or freed) when calling a new function, and ST1 to ST7 must be empty on exiting a function. ST0 must also be empty when not used for returning a value.

Your code clobbers *EAX*, *EBX*, *ECX*, and *EDX*. You are free to destroy the contents of *EAX*, *ECX*, and *EDX* but you *must preserve EBX*. If you don't you can cause problems for the *C* code calling the function. After you do the `enter 0,0` instruction you can `push ebx` and just before each `leave` instruction you can do `pop ebx`

If you were to use `-O1`, `-O2`, or `-O3` *GCC* compiler options to enable optimizations your program *may* not work as expected or crash altogether.